# MySQL Unistall & and Root user

Tags: windows

Because I had forget the root password from MySQL, I have try to unistall MySQL and delete /data/ folder. When I had install again MySQL, it ask me for current root passowrd. I use the (GUI) Installer for Windows. So how can I delete the root username;

I had also try [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/resetting-permissions.html) solution, but it doesn't work. I think its something about the first install. I am afraid that I made two services, but I searches from them and had found only one and has been deleted from the unistall.

Am not I wannabe db admin or something. I just want to use SAM Broadcaster and support team had say to try MySQL. So I Just want install mysql for SAM Broadcaster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of reinstalling mysql, you can easily reset root password. Check this manual for more info: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html

Comment: Thanks for you time. I have already do what say this link, in fact only the Windows part. It seem that change the password, but it doesn't. Its possible something like that I have to mysql services or installs, and I change the pass from one and not in another? How can see if my thought is correct?